# Html Page Break not working

Tags: html, css, printing

Trying to set a page break in the page I'm working on but in the print preview I'm still seeing things on the page that aren't supposed to be there. Can't figure out why this isn't working.

In my css style:

```
.applicant-break hr {page-break-after:always;}
```

In my ASP.NET code...partial view of code the start tags are there:

```
<b>Resume</b>
<br />
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litResume"></asp:Literal>
<br />
<br />             
<hr class="applicant-break" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>  
</asp:Panel>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your css needs to be

```
hr.applicant-break {page-break-after:always;}
```

EDIT:

Doing some reading on the [W3Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp), it seems this css property is meant for table elements

> "Set the page-breaking behavior to always break after a table element"

EDIT:

Doing some more reading, it seems browsers do support more than the table element, however some browsers have trouble with it on HR and BR tags ([Reading here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml))

try putting a div after the hr like so

```
<hr />
<div class="applicant-break"></div>
```

and changing your CSS to

```
div.applicant-break {page-break-after:always;}
```

Comment: hmmm, it's still not printing out correctly after that change.

Comment: If this doesn't work there is some other CSS interfering with it, or your html is not well formed. Is there any other css you've applied to hr or applicant-break ?

Comment: Are there items being printed out onto the page?

Comment: nope hr and applicant-break dont have anything else. There are items on the page when it prints out, it's everything I want to see just not on the correct pages. Could it be because I'm using an hr tag? I heard page-break only works with specific tags.

Answer (score 3):

So apparently I'm silly, I was trying to trust the print preview of Chrome instead of just actually printing it myself, upon printing it I see that the page break does in fact work, thanks for your assistance m.t! :)

So fair warning to anyone else reading this, while it is useful it doesn't always give you an accurate look at your print job all the time.

Comment: Odd, it seemed to work with me on the HR with chrome in print preview