# page-break-* doesn't work on Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, safari

I know that there're lots of questions on this topic, but I still could not find a working solution. So, here's my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row print-break">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
          <!-- Some Content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row print-break">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
          <!-- Some Content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row print-break">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
          <!-- Some Content -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And css:

```
@media print {
   .print-break {
      page-break-after: always;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
   }
}
```

And it happens that Firefox insert page breaks properly; Chrome and Safari doesn't.

Do anyone know how to overcome this? Or where am I possibly wrong?

Comment: I know that setting `float:none` on a parent would work, but sometimes, I guess, it could break the layout, so this solution doesn't count.

Comment: I'm sure this is a typo when pasting the code here, but shouldn't `className` be `class`?

Comment: Did you google it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303178/page-break-doesnt-work-on-google-chrome or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884380/css-page-break-not-working-in-all-browsers maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614808/html-page-break-not-working or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989843/page-break-after-always-not-working-when-printing

Comment: @imvain2, yes that was a typo, I copied code my jsx file and forgot to replace `className` with `class` everywhere.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, yes, I googled it, I saw all these links and many others before asking the  question.

Answer (score 2):

Your specific code has a few items of discussion, these individually are correct, but together cause your issue.

Unfortunately `page-break-after` works differently from browser to browser, one cannot assume a behaviour and we thus need to revert to a simpler, known behaviour.

Some browsers will not page-break on a div with a **parent** that has a `float` and/or has a `width`.

I'm assuming from your code that you're using Bootstrap (?).  You have a nested grid in the code:  The outer row/col is 12 wide.  (Why nest inside a 12-wide parent?)  This outer col sets a `width: 100%`, so Safari will not page-break it's children - so your nested items will not page-break.

I can't tell why you're nesting on a 12-wide, but if you can remove that then your page-break will work.

*I personally also page-break in an independent, separator tag (a `div` or a `span`) - this makes the code easier to read and I can also style the tag if I wish.*

*You also don't need to `row` each row, just a `clearfix` will 'new row', and this allows us to use that same separator.*

An un-nested rewrite of your code thus then works (or it does in my Safari):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    Some Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="print-break clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    Some Content 2
  </div>
  <div class="print-break clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    Some Content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS wil be:

```
@media print {
  .print-break {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

*(You don't really need `@media print` - it's superfluous in this context.)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that element with `page-break-after: always;` has no parents with `float` property set to other value than `none;`, also check that it's a `block` element. If it's `inline-block` element, it won't apply page break at all.